# Align UV verticles into perfect circle

Tags: uv, add-on, uv-image-editor

So i've been trying to align verticles inside UV editor into perfect circle without unwrapping, since doing so will break UV due to complexity of mesh...or rather, trying to find simple solution. I know there was an addon that allowed to do so, with some other neat things, but i simply forgot it's everything :/

I used to work in blender 2.8* and 2.9 for some time with it, but (as bafoon i am) deleted addon with older versions of blender because main disk was filled with trash.

In essence, it works like loop-tools circle option: any amount of verticles would align into perfect circle shape.

**Yes i know magic UV has similar option,** but that addon doesn't work on interior verticles (neither outside nor inside rim ones), and i need exactly that.

Does anyone remember/has any idea of what i need?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [textools](https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender)?

Comment: Tried. Textools doesn't have this feature. And APPARENTLY i found it: UV_Tool. Sorry for inconvenience, guys! https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-uv-tool/576877

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was UV_Tool addon. It also has neat smooth setting and straigten to equal distance.

Here: https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-uv-tool/576877